# Have new and medium-experienced users' posts dropped off recently?

Tags: discussion, support

Have new and medium-experienced users' posts dropped off recently?  Is anyone keeping track of such stats?

Comment: [This query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/writers/query/653047/daily-site-activity-graph?Days=365&VScale=7&WindowSize=3#graph) shows you the 5k rep info that you could see in the site analytics. I've written more about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336882/352819) and the question [Is there a mechanism for closing graduated SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342915/352819), which is specifically about Writing.SE, should give you more than enough information. In short: yes! That is exactly what happened. Most kinds of activity have dropped massively.

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname - Thank you very much.  The query appears to suggest that the questions have held steady.  I am concerned that newcomers may not be realizing what's going on. Also, I don't see, so far, an indication that the creation of a specific alternative site is having a dramatic effect. // The site shutdown idea sounds intriguing -- but I would want to see the alternative site plastered all over the place, to capture the newcomers.  Hopefully the company would turn a blind eye to this, since their sacrosanct technical sites would remain.

Comment: As I mentioned on your other meta question they won't allow this. And most new users don't even read the help center, let alone meta or other questions on main (there was one question about comparing the site with this one by [this user](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/37845/sesquipedalias) but apparently that question was also deleted). Don't hold your breath for every new user to migrate. In time this site will die (or maybe slowly recover with a new community). Most of the old community left and is only occasionally checking the site out of habit and to tell others where we are.

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname - thank you. Some ideas: all new questions could be answered with a link to an answer at the alternate site; all new questions could be answered by people with the alternate site in their user name; an agreement could be made not to post any candidates; a request could be made for shutdown.  The last idea seems to be the worst since there would be no redirection.  One more: negotiate with the company for a redirect.  I don't think they really care what happens to the small sites.

Comment: People have tried to explicitly redirect others. The fact that *you don't know about this* and that *you can't find out anything* about this if you haven't seen it right after it was posted goes to show how much they are pruning the *explicit* stuff. They **won't** advertise another site and allow explicit advertising of it. What you have seen so far - the posts directing to external sources which in turn are explicit - is the maximum that's allowed. Everything else is removed and users are being suspended for it. Sorry, but hoping for a redirect is simply naive at this point.

Comment: Related: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2282/29719

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname - perhaps something to negotiate.  I can't imagine that a small site like Writing would be producing significant revenue.  All the company communications recently have been studiously ignoring the existence of the small sites.

Comment: I am only interested in watching how the company and the new community handle the situation here. Whether the site survives, dies or slowly fades into a barely-alive state is irrelevant to me personally. Not sure why you want to kill it so desperately, but that's up to you. If you aren't satisfied with the information that I have provided about others that have tried things similar to what you have proposed feel free to ignore it and contact SE with the "Contact Us" button. That's *by far* your best chance to talk to those that might be willing to listen and can actually *do* something.

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname - Ha.  I tried that in, I think it was October, and then again in November.  Nothing. // Sorry if I appeared to wish the site harm.  Look, when the s - - -  first hit the fan at the end of September, moderators started resigning or taking breaks, as a show of solidarity with Monica, and concern for the network.  It was quasi-organized.  It didn't actually function remotely like a strike action.  I went elsewhere and requested a temporary place to shift our activities to, and the answer was no, the decision had already been made that it would be all hands on deck...

Comment: ...to build something better, and no temporary venue would be set up.  I stopped attending.  Something happened recently, and now Writing is our guinea pig.  Writing now has an alternative venue.  Hurray!  I'm wondering what the company would do if there were no moderators left.  Assign Writing moderation to an overworked staff member?  Shut it down?  At first that seemed intriguing -- but what if it could be kept alive (on life support) in order to direct newcomers to the alternative?  For this to work, it would be important to find effective ways of notifying the newcomers.

Comment: "I'm wondering what the company would do if there were no moderators left." You are still talking about this as if it was some theoretical "What if...?" scenario. There *are* no mods left on Writing. Cyn is inactive. I still don't know why you think shutting the site down is "intriguing" and frankly I don't care why you find it fascinating. Other sites have been shut down in the past, this one may or may not be shut down, too, at some point. We'll see. Maybe the company will listen to you now. Maybe not. It's not up to the users. It's up to the company. You have to convince *them*.

Comment: @SecSE-clearMonica'sname - Ah, I didn't realize that the moderator listed is no longer active.  Has the company given any indication how this situation is, and will be, handled?  For example, what happens when a flag is raised?

Comment: [Once in the beginning](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/what-are-we-supposed-to-do-now-about-discipline-issues#comment6004_2252) one CM handled something and recently after the meta post about shutting down the site [another one reopened a question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/49552/timeline). Other than that only the spam-deletion of the question I mentioned above and [a post that basically read like 'You guys should have just asked' even though we did ask quite a couple times for enabling higher rep level](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/23159)

Comment: So they do a little bit every couple months if they are on the site for other reasons as far as I can see. Or when someone posts links to the other site... Maybe they do a bit of spam deletion in the background as is usual policy with mods fighting spam. Who knows? Other than that I have to tell you again that posting here on meta won't get you answers. You need to ask the company. They are the only ones who can really tell you what happens and what they are doing or planning. In theory at least. Whether they *will* tell you is another story.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104074/discussion-between-aparente001-and-sec-se-clear-monicas-name).

Comment: It's kinda hard to ignore when everyone here is named Monica.

Comment: Yep. SE is going down the toilet fast. It's been enjoyable to watch :D

Comment: @Secespitus, the SEDE query in your first comment will soon become useless when the critical date drifts out of the window.  Perhaps it could be updated to either have a fixed window or a window that always starts in the middle of 2019.

Comment: @RayButterworth You can look at the screenshot in the answer behind the [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336882/352819) hyperlink that I wrote in that comment to see what it looked like when I wrote those posts. Alternatively feel free to adapt the query that I found there and share the results, but I won''t invest any time into this matter. With the screenshot it should be enough. The site is dead and most people have moved on, some of us just stick around to read some of the answers on other sites for which we don't yet have any other places.